# Legal Issue: Remove/Hide links on Google Login page

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

**For the background:**
I'm developing a device application which offers connection to Google Drive. My end-users will need to login to their Google Account and authorize my application to access their Google Drive.

I'm using OAuth 2.0 to do this. But my concern is that I don't want users to navigate away from my application using the links on the Google Login page. Basically, I don't want them to use my application to browse the internet.

**Question:**
Will I violate any terms of service/usage if I hide or change the href the links using GreaseMonkey or TamperMonkey? The changes will only be on the client side and I won't alter any processing at all.

I already checked https://developers.google.com/terms/ but I found no item related to modifying the pages on client side.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of device?  If you’re on Android, check out the Google Drive API and GoogleAuthUtil, you probably don’t need to code your own OAuth 2 support.  On iOS we’ve been shipping a bunch of library-ware to help you similarly.

But if you’re doing OAuth 2 via a browser, it would be highly inappropriate to screw around with the Google Login page.  Also I suspect that the page will try to resist such attempts, but I don’t know the details.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for checking out my question.
Sorry, I can't really tell you want kind of device but it's not for mobile use. Basically, the device will have something like a web container which will display the web pages but I don't want it to be use for browsing the internet.
I have control with this web container so I can add some onload javascript commands to remove/modify the links on the device side only. My only concern is if it's okay with Google's Term of Service.